# slower performance of kernel level memcpy in 4.4.x kernel on powerpc architecture

Tags: linux, performance, linux-kernel, memcpy, powerpc

I have a board with PowerPC processor and some DSP cores.
I was running 2.6.34 version linux kernel based Windriver release on it. Recently I built 4.4.106 version kernel based OS for my board and booted it up. With this I have problem in booting up my DSP cores.

On debugging, I figured out that memcpy() ( Kernel space memcpy , not the user space libc's memcpy ) in 4.4.106 kernel taking slightly more time than that in 2.6.34 . 
Further I replaced the memcpy functionality provided in arch/powerpc/lib/memcpy_64.S with older one in 2.6.x ( which is a bad idea , I know) but still I did not see any performance improvement.
Can anyone let me know what all other factors that could be influencing the performance of memcpy in kernel space.
I could think of preemption factor , which I am testing right now. I disabled all configurations related to kernel stats. Is there any thing else I need to look into to get the needed performance improvement.

Comment: You mentioned that it's "taking slightly more time" - how are you measuring that? Is this part of an overall benchmark workload, or are you doing specific measurement of `memcpy`?

Comment: i wrote a small module which on insertion will copy a random text of 1KB for 1024 times to a kmalloc ed space of 1MB. This copying of 1MB repeats for given number of times ( typically more than 500 times. We note the timestamps before starting the copying and immediately after the completion of copying 500MB. The difference in between the timestamps is considered as time took for copying.